# OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled.. On a line after calling glEnable(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I keep getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLChecks.ensureArrayVBOenabled(GLChecks.java:93)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertexPointer(GL11.java:2680)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.render(TerrainDemo.java:2074)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.enterGameLoop(TerrainDemo.java:3266)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame(TerrainDemo.java:3490)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.resartTDemo(Test2.java:55)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.main(Test2.java:41)
```

However, the array buffer object IS enabled!

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

As you can see, two lines before the glVertexPointer call (the one that the error is at), then I am clearly enabling the array buffer!

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Vertex Buffers are not something you enable or disable - LWJGL is misleading you.

You need to undertand that the `glVertexPointer` command uses whatever is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` ("Array Buffer Object") as its memory source (beginning with OpenGL 1.5).

In certain versions of OpenGL (1.5-3.0 and 3.1+ compatibility) if you have **0** bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then the last parameter to `glVertexPointer` is an actual *pointer* to your ***program's*** memory (client memory) rather than an *offset* into GPU memory (server memory). *Core OpenGL 3.1+ does not even support client-side vertex storage, so that last parameter is always an offset.*

---

#### LWJGL's error message is poorly worded:

> Exception in thread "main" *org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException*: **Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled.**

The error message really means that you have **0** bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you call `glVertexPointer (...)`. LWJGL apparently considers Array Buffer Objects ***"disabled"*** whenever nothing is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. That is not *too* unreasonable, but it does lead you to believe that this is a state that can be enabled or disabled using `glEnable` or `glDisable`; it is not.

Remember how I described the last parameter to `glVertexPointer` as an *offset* when you have something bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`? Since LWJGL is Java-based, there is no way to pass an arbitrary memory address as an integer. An integer value passed to `glVertexPointer (...)` *must* be an offset into the currently bound vertex buffer's memory.

#### Client-side vertex specification <sub>(unsupported in core GL 3.1+)</sub>

```
void glVertexPointer(int size, int type, int stride, java.nio.ByteBuffer pointer);
```

#### Server-side vertex specification <sub>(takes an ***offset*** into `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`)</sub>

```
void glVertexPointer(int size, int type, int stride, long pointer_buffer_offset);
```

As you can see, there is an alternate form of the `glVertexPointer` function in LWJGL that can take memory not stored in a buffer object, where you pass a specialization of `java.nio.Buffer`. That is the form you are expected to use when you have no vertex buffer bound and ***that*** is what the error message is really telling you.

---

#### That explains what the error message you are seeing actually means, but not its cause.

For some reason `vboVertexHandle` appears to be **0** or some value not generated using `glGenBuffers (...)` in your application. Showing the code where you initialize the VBO would be helfpul.

Comment: That is the sort of reply I would expect for a bounty of 200 question to get! Thank you so much for your answer!

I am now using a new object rendering technique which had not required those 2 variables, meaning the variables are never initialized.

Answer (score 1):

GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is not one of the allowed values to glEnable. If you want to attach a vertex buffer object to the vertex pointer, you have to enable it using the glEnableClientState method:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L); //This is line 2074 of the TerrainDemo class.
```

Side note: This functionality is deprecated since OpenGL 3 Core Profile. If there is no restriction on sticking to this old OpenGL version, it would be a good idea to start with modern OpenGL (especially since you're already using vbos).